# Using gdb for fork() system call

Tags: c, operating-system, fork, system-calls

I want to use gdb for looking into the various details of the fork() system call. To do this, I used one breakpoint at the fork() and from there onwards i am using step command but this way it is not working fine.

Can somebody explain me how to use gdb to look into every single step occuring during fork() system call?

Comment: Are you trying to single-step into the kernel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see whats happening best if to look at the kernel code first, [check it here](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/kernel/fork.c?v=linux-2.6#L1409).

I don't think you can single step through kernel from user space. You can use virtual server to do the debugging using KGDB. Check [blog post here](http://fotis.loukos.me/blog/?p=25). Or you can use [KGDB](http://book.opensourceproject.org.cn/embedded/embeddedprime/opensource/0136130550/ch14lev1sec2.html) on main kernel.

Comment: Of course you can't step through kernel space from user space, that's the whole point of kernel space and user space separation.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you meant that you want to follow the child process instead of the parent once the fork is called? In that case:

> If you want to follow the child
> process instead of the parent process,
> use the command set follow-fork-mode.
>
> **set follow-fork-mode** *mode*
>
> Set the debugger response to a program call of fork or vfork. A call
> to fork or vfork creates a new
> process. The mode argument can be:
>
> **parent**: The original process is debugged after a fork. The child
> process runs unimpeded. This is the
> default.
>
> **child**: The new process is debugged after a fork. The parent process runs
> unimpeded.

Comment: Crosslink: Looks like OP actually wants to look into source code of `fork()`. This answer would be appropriate for [c - How do I debug the child process after fork() in gdb? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199270/how-do-i-debug-the-child-process-after-fork-in-gdb/6199292#comment137050385_6199292) .